# Display JSON Object with numbers in Backbone.js Template

Tags: json, backbone.js, console.log

How can I display the following JSON object in Backbone View Template which I got with `console.log`?

```
Object {207: "402", 208: "400", 209: "402", 210: "0", 211: "0", 212: "50", 301: "401", 302: "400"}
```

I did use `<% =207  %>` and `<% =208 %>` in order to get value `"402"` and `"400"`, but it didn't work.

Thank you very much for your help!

(edited)

Hi Vitaliy, are you still there? In this case I got from console.log, how can I print the value of "timestamp" and also "101"?

Object {timestamp: "2013-06-26T17:36:03+0530", values: Object}
   timestamp: "2013-06-26T17:36:03+0530"
   values: Object
   101: "81"
   102: "1500"
   201: "49"
   **proto**: Object

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use numbers as object keys. This is syntax error. Modify your object keys like that `{"key_207": "402", ...}`

Also to print result you should use `<%= key_207 %>` instead of `<% =key_207 %>`

The best way to fix this issue is to **modify server response on the server side**.

But also you can try do this (I'm not sure if it will work in all browsers):

```
var res = {207: "402", 208: "400"};
console.log(res[207]); // -> 402
```

So you need to pass your model to template inside some object and acces to key in the way above:

```
__template__({data:this.model.toJSON()})
```

And then:

```
<%= data[207] %>
```

Comment: Thank you Vitaliy! Could you tell me how I could modify the object keys of JSON object?

Comment: Hi Vitaliv, are you still there? In this case I got from console.log, how can I print the value of "timestamp" and also "101"?

Object {timestamp: "2013-06-26T17:36:03+0530", values: Object}
timestamp: "2013-06-26T17:36:03+0530"
values: Object
101: "81"
102: "1500"
201: "49"
__proto__: Object

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `<%= data.timestamp %>` and `<%= data.values[101] %>`

Comment: This time the console log said: "Cannot read property '101' of undefined". I think after I used this.changePage(new ValuesView({model:this.valuesCollection})); the data has come to the Backbone Template. What is your opinion?

Comment: Hey Vinaliy, I even cannot get timestamp. Could you help me?

__template__({data:this.model.toJSON()})---> can it be changed to something like 
__template__({data.timestamp:this.model.toJSON()})

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `__template__` this is not valid template generation. I added it as example. This syntax is not valid - `{data.timestamp:...}` use this `{data:{timestamp:...}}` instead.

Comment: That's very kind of you! I will try them :)